# Grid layout offset adjustment and non-uniform columns in LMTX

Tags: context, grids, grid-typesetting

I'm trying to emulate the style of [Jean-Luc Doumont's](https://www.principiae.be/pdfs/TUG-X-004-slideshow.pdf) presentation. Here is his slide, with a grid overlay (please open in a new window of image viewer as the gridlines are hard to see on tex.stackexchange):

[image: JL's slide]

This is what I currently have:

[image: my slide]

There are two problems with my current attempt:

1. The grid doesn't divide the text area evenly, the first line is shorter than the rest, and additional space appears at the bottom.How should I make the grid fit the text area such that all line heights are equal?
2. The grid in the text area is 21.5 units wide. The 0.5 unit is at the beginning leading to a non-uniform grid. How should I configure the columnsets to get this first column to be half the width of the rest?

Note that I set the `columndistance` to `1pt` instead of `\zeropoint` just in order to showcase the problem.

The end goal is to use columnsets to align content, just like in the reference slide.

My current code:

```
\definemeasure[xheight][0.1in]
\definemeasure[base][3\measured{xheight}]

\definepapersize[slide][width=80\measured{xheight},height=60\measured{xheight}]
\setuppapersize[slide]

\setupinterlinespace[line=\measure{base}]

\setuplayout[
leftedge=\zeropoint,
rightedge=\zeropoint,
leftedgedistance=\zeropoint,
rightedgedistance=\zeropoint,
leftmargin=\zeropoint,
rightmargin=\zeropoint,
leftmargindistance=\zeropoint,
rightmargindistance=\zeropoint,
width=middle,
cutspace=2\measured{base},
backspace=2\measured{base},
topspace=2\measured{base},
header=\zeropoint,
height=middle,
bottomspace=2\measured{base},
footer=\zeropoint,
grid=yes,
columndistance=1pt, % should be \zeropoint
columns=21.5]


\showframe
\showgrid

\starttext
\input tufte
\stoptext
```